# How to find the probability that none of your numbers will be among the 4 selected by the lottery

Tags: probability

This was a question on my first class in probability.

Question:

In Lotto 4-26, the lottery picks 4 numbers (without replacement) from 1 to 26. Before this drawing is done, you pick 4 numbers (without replacement) from 1 to 26. Find the probability that none of your numbers will be among the 4 selected by the lottery.

My Attempt:

Let $D$ be the number of outcomes in $S$ (sample space) and $C$ be the number of outcomes in $E$(events) Probability = $\frac{C}{D}$

$D = 26 * 26 * 26 * 26$ (the reasoning behind this was that there are 4 numbers each with the possibility of being 1 of 26 numbers)

$C = event$ (I am not sure how I would come up with this part)

$ 1 - \frac{C}{26 * 26 * 26 * 26}$ (the reasoning behind subtracting from 1 was because the question asked for the probability that *none* of my numbers were selected.)

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: There are only ${26\choose4}$ ways to pick four numbers without replacement.  $26^4$ is the number *with* replacement.  As for C, the way to choose none of your numbers is to choose them all from the $22$ you didn't pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in total $26 \choose 4$ ways to select $4$ numbers from 26  numbers !

You are allowed to pick 4 numbers. None of your selected numbers will be maong those 4 selected by Lotto if and only if the 4 numbers chosen by Lotto are among the rest of the 22 , hence desired probability $= \frac{22 \choose 4}{26 \choose 4}$